# Prevent calling a web service too many times

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I provide a Web Service for my clients which allow him to add a record to the production database.

I had an incident lately, in which my client's programmer called the service in a loop , iterated to call to my service thousands of times.

My question is what would be the best way to prevent such a thing.

I thought of some ways:
1.At the entrence to the service, I can update counters for each client that call the service, but that looks too clumbsy.
2.Check the IP of the client who called this service, and raise a flag each time he/she calls the service, and then reset the flag every hour.

I'm positive that there are better ways and would appriciate any suggestions.

Thanks, David

Comment: Another idea, Updating the session of this user :

Comment: I presume you have some kind of "bulk" add method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way is to store on the session a counter and use the counter to prevent too many calls per time.

But if your user may try to avoid that and send different cookie each time*, then you need to make a custom table that act like the session but connect the user with the ip, and not with the cookie.

One more here is that if you block basic on the ip you may block an entire company that come out of a proxy. So the final correct way but more complicate is to have **both ip and cookie connected with the user** and know if the browser allow cookie or not. If not then you block with the ip. The difficult part here is to know about the cookie. **Well on every call you can force him to send a valid cookie that is connected with an existing session**. If not then the browser did not have cookies.

[ * ] The cookies are connected with the session.
[ * ] By making new table to keep the counters and disconnected from session you can also avoid the session lock.

In the past I have use a code that used for DosAttack, but none of them are working good when you have many pools and difficult application so I now use a custom table as I describe it. This are the two code that I have test and use

[Dos attacks in your web app](http://omaralzabir.com/prevent_denial_of_service__dos__attacks_in_your_web_application/)

[Block Dos attacks easily on asp.net](http://madskristensen.net/post/Block-DoS-attacks-easily-in-ASPNET.aspx)

How to find the clicks per seconds saved on a table. Here is the part of my SQL that calculate the Clicks Per Second. One of the tricks is that I continue to add clicks and make the calculation of the average if I have 6 or more seconds from the last one check. This is a code snipped from the calculation as an idea

```
set @cDos_TotalCalls = @cDos_TotalCalls + @NewCallsCounter

SET @cMilSecDif = ABS(DATEDIFF(millisecond, @FirstDate, @UtpNow))

-- I left 6sec diferent to make the calculation
IF @cMilSecDif > 6000
    SET @cClickPerSeconds = (@cDos_TotalCalls * 1000 / @cMilSecDif)
else
    SET @cClickPerSeconds = 0

IF @cMilSecDif > 30000
    UPDATE ATMP_LiveUserInfo SET cDos_TotalCalls = @NewCallsCounter, cDos_TotalCallsChecksOn = @UtpNow WHERE cLiveUsersID=@cLiveUsersID         
ELSE IF @cMilSecDif > 16000
    UPDATE ATMP_LiveUserInfo SET cDos_TotalCalls = (cDos_TotalCalls / 2), 
    cDos_TotalCallsChecksOn = DATEADD(millisecond, @cMilSecDif / 2, cDos_TotalCallsChecksOn)
        WHERE cLiveUsersID=@cLiveUsersID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Lets say that I update the Session: Session["ServiceInvoked"]=true; and ask if we ask at the begining of the session : if((bool)Session["ServiceInvoked"]) ... I will prevent the call. BUT, how would i reset it after , lets say , an hour?

Comment: If I will insert the Datetime, I can work since I can check the Session Datetime Subscract the DateTime.Now, and allow the service to be invoke....

Comment: @DavidRasuli You use a DateTime field of the last update together with the counter and you make an average calculation - you see for example on the last DateTime that the last ask was before 1 second and all ready have 10 calls. With other words you cut it for the last calls, not for the one now.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to have a look at the *legal* aspects of your situation: **Does the contract with your client allow you to restrict the client's access?**

This question is out of the scope of SO, but you must find a way to answer it. Because if you are legally bound to process all requests, then there is no way around it. Also, the legal analysis of your situation may already include some limitations, in which way you may restrict the access. That in turn will have an impact on your solution.

All those issues aside, and just focussing on the *technical* aspects, do you use some sort of user authentication? (If not, why not?) If you do, you can implement whatever scheme you decide to use on a per user base, which I think would be the cleanest solution (you don't need to rely on IP addresses, which is a somehow ugly workaround).

Once you have your way of identifying a single user, you can implement several restrictions. The fist ones that come to my mind are these:

1. *Synchronous processing*
   Only start processing a request after all previous requests have been processed. This may even be implemented with nothing more but a `lock` statement in your main processing method. If you go for this kind of approach,
2. *Time delay between processing requests*
   Requires that after one processing call a specific time must pass before the next call is allowed. The easiest solution is to store a `LastProcessed` timestamp in the user's session. If you go for this approach, you need to start thinking of how to respond when a new request comes in before it is allowed to be processed - do you send an error message to the caller? I think you should...

**EDIT**
The `lock` statement, briefly explained:

It is intended to be used for thread safe operations. the syntax is as follows:

```
lock(lockObject)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The `lockObject` needs to be an object, usually a private member of the current class. The effect is that if you have 2 threads who both want to execute this code, the first to arrive at the `lock` statement locks the `lockObject`. While it does it's stuff, the second thread can not acquire a lock, since the object is already locked. So it just sits there and waits until the first thread releases the lock when it exits the block at the `}`. Only thhen can the second thread lock the `lockObject` and do it's stuff, blocking the `lockObject` for any third thread coming along, until it has exited the block as well.

Careful, the whole issue of thread safety is far from trivial. (One could say that the only thing trivial about it are the many trivial errors a programmer can make ;-) 
[See here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for an introduction into threading in C#

Comment: Great answer Treb, Can you please elaborate a bit more about the "lock" statement as I'm not familiar with it?

Comment: @David: `lock` is documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Get user ip and insert it into cache for an hour after using web service, this is cached on server:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("UserIp", true,  null,DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

When you need to check if user entered in last hour:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Cache["UserIp"] != null)
{
 //means user entered in last hour
}
```